# merging two tables by placing data when condition satisfies

Tags: python, mysql

I have two tables 'A' and 'B'.I need to join two tables when a1 and v1 are same,then it should take the respective data as explained below.

```
A

id a1   a2
1  hi   hello
2  see  when
3  bee  animal

B
no. v1   v2       
1   bee  null
2   see  null
```

The expected output:
Here,when it finds any data `a1` in A with that of `v1` in B ,when both are similar then it should get the respective data from `a2` to `v2`

```
B
no. v1   v2       
1   bee  animal
2   see  when
```

My coding:

```
import MySQLdb
import os
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                         user="root", # your username
                          passwd="mysql", # your password
                          db="sakila") # name of the data base
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN v2 B ON A.a1=B.v2")
db.commit()
```

I am not sure on how far its correct,please rectify my code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change your query. Somthing like this:-

```
 SELECT B.NO, B.v1 AS V1, A.a2 AS V2
 FROM A INNER JOIN B
 WHERE A.a1 = B.v1;
```